# Binding a variable and pass it into context

Tags: javascript, bind

In the following code, the second console.log prints component as 'undefined', how can I pass the 'component', which is accessible in the outer context to the inner context ?

I tried to use bind() but it didn't work (it still prints it as 'undefined')

```
function(component) {
    console.log(component); // component is printed in the console
    $A.test.addWaitFor(true, function() {
        debugger;
        console.log(component); // component is undefined ! 
    }, function() {//do the job};
}
```

Comment: without the debugger statement if you `console.log` `component` do you get the same behaviour?  This looks like `component` *should* be in the closure.

Comment: yeah, that works. but how does the debugger affect the situation ?

Comment: I guess that depends on what browser you are using.